# contract instance has a null transactionHash

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have migrated the contract via truffle, code [like this](https://gist.github.com/minishine/da46867d9de43a6af6cdc4eb5caf9412), very simple
and it returns the contract account address

```
[root@localhost c2]# truffle migrate
Compiling ./contracts/Ballot.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Ballot...
  Ballot: 0x2eb2128b3150bd4b95e96540b7e2d2151bcfb2cc
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
```

then I created the contract instance like this

```
myBallot = eth.contract(abi).at(addr)
```

`abi` and `addr` are vars, and they are certainly right, then

```
myBallot
{
  abi: [{
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "vote",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      type: "function"
    }
    …………
  ],
  address: "0x071d808a15df658c0b39b71d127f4df05bb66abb",
  transactionHash: null,
  allEvents: function(),
  chairperson: function(),
  giveRightToVote: function(),
  proposals: function(),
  vote: function(),
  voteCast: function(),
  voters: function(),
  winnerName: function(),
  winningProposalIndex: function()
}
```

the `transactionHash` is null

and then I call the function `myBallot.giveRightToVote(eth.accounts[0]);`  and continue minned, the voters is still empty

```
 myBallot.voters()
[false, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Check that your account is unlocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating the contract instance with an address. You haven't told `eth.contract` anything about a transaction, so there's no reason why you should be seeing a transaction hash.

Comment: after executed `myBallot = eth.contract(abi).at(addr)`, then `txpool.status`, the pending was still 0, so what should I do to make the instance have a normal  transaction hash?

Comment: You don't need it to have a transaction hash. It's not a transaction. When you call giveRightToVote against it, that will be a transaction, and that (not the contract instance) will produce a transaction hash.